# Will didReceiveRemoteNotification called in foreground mode when content-available set as true in payload?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Push notification is not receiving when the app runs in foreground when `"content-available":true` in payload. But Notification is received when app is not running in foreground.

Also I have added "Required Background Modes" for Background fetch and Remote Notification. And I'm using `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method to handle push message which is calling when app is not running and but not calling only in foreground mode.

I want to download some contents from sever even the app is running in foreground using silent push notification. is there any other way to receive push notification in foreground mode with `"content-available":true` payload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably implemented didReceiveRemoteNotification:. Implement didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: instead.

Comment: I'm using the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method only. Please see my above edits.

Comment: Are you sure your payload does not contain either alert, sound or badge in the aps dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that I have included "content-available":true only in aps dic.

Comment: If it contains content-available and either of alert,sound,badge its not guaranteed it will work correctly. So make sure you don't have those last 3.